# Android app permission

Tags: android, security, permissions

I was wondering, when we download an app which is very cool but before you install it ask to give permission for almost everything you have on the phone. Even that app can make call without your permission to your contacts. Given this scenario, how do we say an unrooted device where app data is secured from other app access? if I have an app which stores data on the device memory then would that be accessed by one of those app which takes all permission before installed?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps are still sandboxed, they can't access each others internal storage even with requested permissions.

I'm not sure this is the correct forum for your question though as it's not related to developing. This isn't the right site for IT support.

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments - anything put somewhere insecure location such as the SD card would be readable, but the default file storage is a bit more secure.

From the android docs (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

> Note: Your app's internal storage directory is specified by your app's
>   package name in a special location of the Android file system.
>   Technically, another app can read your internal files if you set the
>   file mode to be readable. However, the other app would also need to
>   know your app package name and file names.  Other apps cannot browse your internal directories and do not have read or write access unless you explicitly set the files to be readable or writable.

Comment: I guess that "stores data on the device memory" is a bit vague, if you're referring to SharedPreferences of SQLite you're probably right, but if the data is stored on a file - it's accessible given the right permission.